# What's the easiest way to detect the user's operating system in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Simple Rails app, mostly scaffolding. I want to detect whether the user is using Android or iPhone to access my app. What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/android|iphone/)
  puts "yup, its mobile"
end
```

Comment: I use /android|iphone|ipod/i in my regex to catch the iPod Touch. It also lets you drop the downcase (i is case-insensitive).

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is old, but in case this helps someone else, I use this method in `application_controller.rb` to automatically set the format to `:mobile`:

```
before_filter :detect_mobile

protected

def detect_mobile
  request.format = :mobile if mobile?
end

def mobile?
  request.user_agent =~ /iPhone|iPad|Android/i
end
```

The `mobile?` method is separate so that you can also use it in your own controllers if you need to do some sort of conditional logic for mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def getBrowser(bt)
    rs=false
    ua=request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase
    isOpera = ua.index('opera') ? true : false
    isSafari = (ua =~ /webkit|khtml/) ? true : false
    isSafari3 = (ua.index('webkit/5') ? true : false
    isGecko = (!isSafari and ua.index('gecko')) ? true : false
    isGecko3 = (!isSafari and ua.index('rv:1.9')) ? true : false
    isIE = (!isOpera and ua.index('msie')) ? true : false
    isIE7 = (!isOpera and ua.index('msie 7')) ? true : false
    case bt
      when 0  #isKonqueror
        if ua.index('konqueror') then rs=true end
      when 1  #isOpera
        rs=isOpera
      when 2  #isSafari
        rs=isSafari
      when 3  #isSafari2
        rs=isSafari && !isSafari3
      when 4  #isSafari3
        rs=isSafari3
      when 5  #isIE
        rs=isIE
      when 6  #isIE6
        rs=isIE && !isIE7
      when 7  #isIE7
        rs=isIE7
      when 8  #isGecko
        rs=isGecko
      when 9  #isGecko2
        rs=isGecko && !isGecko3
      when 10 #isGecko3
        rs=isGecko3
      when 11 #isWindows
        if ua.index('windows') or ua.index('win32') then rs=true end
      when 12 #isMac
        if ua.index('macintosh') or ua.index('mac os x') then rs=true
end
      when 13 #isAir
        if ua.index('adobeair') then rs=true end
      when 14 #isLinux
        if ua.index('linux') then rs=true end
      when 15 #isSecure
        s = request.env['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].downcase
        if s.index('https') then rs=true end
    end
    rs
  end
```

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/8fa57719fd9316e1

Comment: Where did `bt` come from? [Code-only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5389585).

Answer (score 0):

the user_agent gem is useful for mobile vs. desktop..., and browser version. but doesn't do anything for OS https://github.com/josh/useragent