# Blocking a browser completely in Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, web-applications

Due to multiple issues I'm working through I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to block access to a rails app based on browser? I would like to block Internet Explorer (all versions), thoughts?

Comment: Can't you just add some JavaScript to your site that checks for IE and redirects the browser to the Chrome download page if IE is detected?  Or do you want to prevent IE from even sending a request to your server?

Comment: See this method in another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5125634/536890

Comment: Uh, *why* would you want to block IE? IE6? 7? 8? 9? 10? On the *server* you can try to sniff the UA, but that's about it ..

Comment: @pst Because IE sucks and must be destroyed. There are a growing number of sites that just tell IE users to use a more-compliant browser.

Comment: @DaveNewton I hope that was a joke, because it is a really dumb statement otherwise. Especially considering that IE 9 and IE 10 are in no way comparable to IE 6 or 7 in terms of "sucks". (I don't know why a website developer would want to [ignore 25% of the market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers).)

Comment: @pst Because some developers/companies don't like MS, and I don't really blame them. Maybe I'm just dumb, but oh well--at least I don't go around calling other people dumb, and I'd rather be dumb than do that.

Comment: na he said the statement was dumb, not you personally. Still though, he's right, you shouldn't be serious about doing that, unless it's just some app for fun or something. But you could use `if request.user_agent =~ /MSIE/` in your application controller and have it redirect to a page i suppose.

Comment: I'm sure you could fork & modify this to do your bidding: https://github.com/juliocesar/rack-noie

Comment: @Brian You don't have to fork it -- looks like you could send in the minimum_version as 10 and block all. I'd add that as an answer here.

Comment: Just FYI, if you haven't already, you should see http://www.ie6countdown.com/ - a website created by Microsoft itself.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the rack-noie as Rails middleware:

Gemfile:

```
gem "rack-noie", :require => "noie"
```

Then in your config/application.rb:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::NoIE, {:redirect => "/why-i-dont-support-ie.html", 
                                   :minimum => 29}
```

Of course, this will block IE up till version 29. If you'd rather only let 9 or 10 in, edit away. And where you redirect people is up to you as well.